# How do Tile Coding offsets still cover full state space / affect edge cases?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, state-space-models, q-learning

Reading *Sutton & Barto* I’m having a hard time visualizing the implementation of the tile coding discretization of states.

Specifically, if tilings are offset, how does this effect edge cases? For example, how do the tilings get offset while still having each tiling cover the entire state space? If we have a case where a state resides at the extreme edge (for example, left edge) and a subsequent tiling was offset a bit to the right, would it be omitted in this tilings receptive field?

I’m picturing the way a convolutional filter works when padding with the edges hanging off the relevant area. I can’t figure how the offset works while covering the entire space. The examples in the book didn’t provide much clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one said that each tiling has to cover entire state space, why would it be bad if it didn't? Like you said, corner cases won't be covered by too many tiles but it doesn't matter because they are corner cases so they won't happen often and we don't need too much approximation 'material' to represent them well. It's more important to have good approximation in the 'middle' part of the state space that matters to us. To make a little connection to the convolutional networks (while you already mentioned it), each filter usually only takes care of capturing and representing a certain pattern. No filter will try to cover entire image and find all available patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; this was my initial impression also. But I was confused a bit because the book writes: “ An immediate practical advantage of tile coding is that, because it works with partitions, the overall number of features that are active at one time is the same for any state. Exactly one feature is present in each tiling, so the total number of features present is always the same as the number of tilings.”  Maybe this was a slight oversimplification and omitted the relatively rare corner cases?

Comment: Yes, I think they talked about general case which happens most often .

Comment: Thinking about it for a bit, an idea occured to me that you could, in some specific cases, actually make your tilings cover larger state space than the size of the actual state space is, so all those parts that are covered by only part of the tilings would be out of the state space anyways, so basically all your valid state space could be covered by all tilings

Comment: this was similar to the other thought I had as well. I guess it’s discretionary?

Comment: Yeah, I guess if you know your state space exactly you can tune your parameters (tiles, tillings, offsets) accordingly so that all of it is covered, if you don't know exactly you probably won't be able to do so. In the end it probably depends on the environment and how willing are you to bother with getting everything exactly precise for a small benefit.